# ReactJS .map with a ref to each component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, refs

Working on making it so when a user goes back a page in my react app they will be scrolled to the position on the page they were previously at. Specifically, to the item on a list that they had clicked on.

Current approach is to use the below
const scrollToRef = (ref) => window.scrollTo(0, ref.current.offsetTop)

alongside redux tracking the ref to scroll to & a useEffect hook to scroll to that ref on page load.

however I can't seem to get any refs assigned with my .map.

```
const refs = React.useRef(React.createRef());




      {displayUnavail && !displaySearch
        ? notAvailable.map((tracker) => (
            <IndividualTracker ref={refs.current[tracker]} tracker={tracker} key={tracker.pim} history />
          ))
        : null}
```

Is the issue because i'm doing this on a component directly?

Comment: How are you creating the list `refs.current`?

Comment: const refs = React.useRef(React.createRef());

Comment: Yeah that isn't how you use that hook. Read the docs for `useRef`, but also I think the answer below is good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an empty object to hold your refs.

```js
const allTheRefs = {}
```

Then in each `map` iteration, write the ref to that object, with using the map key as the object key

```js
{displayUnavail && !displaySearch && 
  notAvailable.map((tracker) => (
    <IndividualTracker ref={ref => allTheRefs[tracker.pim] = ref } ... />
  )
}
```

Once your map statement is executed, your `allTheRefs` variable will contain all the refs as key value pairs, with the keys being the `tracker.pim` value, and the value being the ref itself.

### [Here is a working codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/refs-in-a-map-statement-hp8cc)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However this doesn't seem to work. allTheRefs remains empty even after the .map is executed

Comment: I'm not sure of the overall structure of your code - perhaps you can post more for context. 
 What kind of component are you using?  My answer was for use in a functional component.  If you're inside of a class component, you'll have to write it as `allTheRefs = {}`, and `ref={ref => this.allTheRefs[tracker.pim] = ref }`.  Make sure your `const allTheRefs = {}` or `allTheRefs = {}` is declared at the root level of your function or class scope.

Comment: Functional component. allTheRefs is declared at root level of the component

Comment: {displayUnavail && !displaySearch
          ? notAvailable.map((tracker) => <IndividualTracker ref={ref => allTheRefs[tracker.pim] = ref } id={tracker.pim} tracker={tracker} key={tracker.pim} history />)
          : null}

Comment: Refs is just an empty object when page finishing rendering

Comment: Its hard to say what's going wrong without more code.  Where are you checking the value of your refs?  [Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/refs-in-a-map-statement-hp8cc) is a simple working codesandbox.  I'll add it to the answer as well.

Comment: Just wanted to say thanks for your detailed help with this issue way back when, I was a baby, baby dev in over my head.